# search in DataGrid by textBox WPF

Tags: c#, search, datagrid, textbox, grid

I have grid with 10-15 columns. (I load data by datagrid.ItemsSource = myList.ToList()) Also I have textBox witch textChanged event. When I put here eg. "cat" I want to see only rows with value ...cat... 
how do I make this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ queries are good for this sort of thing, the concept goes make a variable to store all of your rows (in the example called `_animals`) and then when the user presses a key in the text box use a query, and pass the result as the `ItemsSource` instead.

Here is a basic working example of how this would work, first the XAML for the Window.

```
<Window x:Class="FilterExampleWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FilterExampleWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Height="22" Margin="10,10,365,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" KeyUp="textBox1_KeyUp" />
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Height="272" Margin="10,40,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Next the code behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace FilterExampleWPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
    {
        List<Animal> _animals;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _animals = new List<Animal>();
            _animals.Add(new Animal { Type = "cat", Name = "Snowy" });
            _animals.Add(new Animal { Type = "cat", Name = "Toto" });
            _animals.Add(new Animal { Type = "dog", Name = "Oscar" });
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = _animals;
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            var filtered = _animals.Where(animal => animal.Type.StartsWith(textBox1.Text));

            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = filtered;            
        }
    }

    public class Animal
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For this example I created an Animal class, however you could substitute it for your own class that you need to filter. Also I enabled AutoGenerateColumns, however adding your own column bindings in WPF would still allow this to work.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution .

```
public class Animal
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    List<Animal> _animals = new List<Animal>();

    public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _animals.Add(new Animal { Type = "cat", Name = "Snowy" });
            _animals.Add(new Animal { Type = "cat", Name = "Toto" });
            _animals.Add(new Animal { Type = "dog", Name = "Oscar" });
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = _animals;
        }
```

```
        List<Animal> filterModeLisst = new List<Animal>();

        private void searchBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            filterModeLisst.Clear();

            if (searchBox.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                filterModeLisst.AddRange(_animals);
            } else
            {
                foreach (Animal anim in _animals)
                {

                    if (anim.Name.Contains(searchBox.Text))
                    {
                        filterModeLisst.Add(anim);
                    }
                }
            }

            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = filterModeLisst.ToList();

        }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.